# list.phtml not overriding/ not reflecting the changes : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, list.phtml

all I am trying to override list.phtml to customize product listing on every product listing pages.
I tried this way.
I have `app/code/<Vendor>_<Module>/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` file and copy list.phtml into my `app/code/<Vendor>_<Module>/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`

But I see no changes to listing even after I run all the upgrade, cache, compile, deploy commands.

catalog_category_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: Instead of default list.phtml you want to show your custom list.phtml ?

Comment: @aravind Yes!. i need to customize the cart button. so i need to override

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml file is invalid try below xml with layout attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Still i am not able to see any changes :( . I am looking the changes in home page product listing section, is that exact place where these changes wil reflect?

Comment: How did you displayed products in home page?

Comment: It all automatically came by magento setup

Comment: `catalog_category_view.xml` for only category page... In home page product listing section might be widget i think...please  find how they implemented

Comment: Or you can see the exact phtml file path by enabling `Stores->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Debug->Enable Template Path Hints for Storefront`

Comment: Are you using sample data Magento instance?...Is your home page look like this http://blankrefer.com/?http://demo-acm-2.bird.eu/?

Comment: I am not using sample data. i am new to magento and when i added two products, it displays in my home page, i was able to override the cart button in detail page. but here i was messed up with it

Comment: I think it's not possible to display by default...let me check about this....mean time use configuration mentioned in above comment to see phtml file and override it.

Comment: Thank for your support :)

Comment: I see the file is grid.phtml in widgets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98656/discussion-between-ranganathan-and-sanjun-dev).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98657/discussion-between-sanjun-dev-and-ranganathan).

Answer (score 1):

You have to just write below `xml` code in your module file,
In your module layout file,

> app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

**File**,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
            <!-- for magento catalog list overrider -->
            <referenceBlock name="category.products.list" template="Vendor_Modulename::product/list.phtml" />          
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override list.phtml with your module by following below code in module's `catalog_category_view.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body> 
        <referenceContainer name="content"> 
             <referenceBlock name="category.products" template="Module_NameSpace_ModuleName::category/list.phtml"/>
           </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Also, if you want to customize the custom module product listing template, then you need to define their block class and your custom template for the same.

Comment: should i really use `category` in `Module_NameSpace_ModuleName::category/list.phtml` ?

Comment: its not compulsory, you can use your folder structure where the list.phtml.is placed in your module